# "Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in vue when updating chart from chart js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

I've created a chart object in mounted() and assigned it to 'myChart' variable declared in data() as I want to be able to use this chart object in other scopes of the code since I heard that there's no way to pass variables declared in mounted to methods.

When I call this.myChart.update(), I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Does anybody know why I got this error and how to rectify it or if there are other ways of accessing variables in mounted from watch or methods?

```
<script>
    import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
    export default {
        name: 'ChartTest',
        props: {
            data: Object,
            title: String,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            myChart:'' //variable declared
        }
    },
    watch: {
        data:function() {
            this.myChart.update()  //error here
        }
    },       
        mounted() {
           const progressChart=new Chart(document.getElementById("progress-chart"), {
                type: 'line',
                data: this.data,
                options: {
                    plugins: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: this.title
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {

                        y: {
                            display: true,
                            stacked: true,
                            max: 0,
                            min: 100,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Your Score (%)'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
           });
            this.myChart=progressChart //assigning myChart variable to chartjs object
    }     
}
</script>
```

Comment: Rather than `data`, you maybe wanted to watch for `myChart`?

Comment: I watched for data cause I will be passing in new data into the data props from another vue file that uses this component, and whenever there's a value change, I want the chart to update with the new data.

Comment: You can't really add new fields to `data`. Add it to some already present object/array rather like `myChart` or `myData`.

Comment: I was able to pass in new data using a similar method when I had the chart in the main vue file (not a component). But now my concern is how to access progressChart from other areas of the code so that I can call update() on it in watch or methods.

Answer (score 1):

chart.js is not 100% fully compatible with Vue. Because chart.js manipulates the DOM directly (perfectly fine for a vanilla js app), this is going to mess with Vue's tracking and managing of the DOM, and it's this tug of war between Vue and chart.js manipulating the DOM that is most likely causing you to see errors about maximum call stack size being exceeded.  There are two work-arounds that I can think of:

1. make your chart non-reactive so that Vue doesn't track it's changes. This is done by creating your myChart variable outside the return statement of the data function:

```js
data() {
    this.myChart = null;
    return {
      // myChart: '' //variable declared
    };
  },
```

Unrelated to the above but an error regardless that you need to fix: you need to set the data before you can call the chart `update()` function

```js
watch: {
    data: function () {
      this.myChart.data = this.data;
      this.myChart.update();
    }
  },
```

Now your chart should work and update, although it won't be reactive.  If that's important to you, why not try

2. [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/), the Vue wrapper implementation of chart.js.  I'm not sure if it has every single bell and whistle of chart.js but will give you a Vue-compatible, reactive chart.

Comment: Do you know if vue-chart.js is supported by vue 3? cause i could not find the answer online and also tried out their basic intro bar chart (followed the guide exactly) but received an error.

Comment: @user121443 this is indeed compatible with Vue as written here: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs#how-to-use